# Adding Image in JLabel but not Responding

Tags: java, image, swing, jlabel, imageicon

I am trying to add image in JLabel but it's not working. The second label is working but the first JLabel is not working.
Here is code.
Thanks in advance.

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Label;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class MainLabel {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        JFrame jframe;
        jframe = createFrame();

        ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon("images.jpeg");

        JLabel label = new JLabel(ii);
        jframe.add(label);

        Label label123 = new Label("Be Nice to World!!");
        jframe.add(label123);

        jframe.setVisible(true);

    }

    static JFrame createFrame() {
        JFrame guiFrame = new JFrame();
        guiFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        guiFrame.setTitle("BorderLayout Example");
        guiFrame.setSize(700, 300);
        return guiFrame;
    }

}
```

Comment: Check `new File("images.jpeg").exists()`.

Comment: System.out.println(new File("images.jpg").exists());
Output of this Line is "true". But the Image is not showing on Jframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `label` which contains the image is being replaced with `label123` in the `BorderLayout.CENTER` position, which *doesnt* have any image attached. You could use:

```
label123.setIcon(ii);
```

If you want the 2 labels to be shown, you could place the text-based `label123` in the `SOUTH` location:

```
jframe.add(label123, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

Note: Use `JLabel` instead of `Label`.

Comment: Yeah it's work if i comment this line "//jframe.add(label123);"
but what if i want to add multiple Jlabels??
Thanks